# Drawing a model from different viewpoints on HTML5 <canvas>

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, graphics, webgl

Well this is for a project I chose to do for my computer graphics class - drawing a grand piano that can be viewed from different angles.

I haven't yet begun the work, and I just completed lynda.com course on [HTML5:Graphics and Animation with Canvas](http://www.lynda.com/HTML-5-tutorials/HTML5-Graphics-and-Animation-with-Canvas/80782-2.html). I can see how one could make a cube, or a ball, those sorts of simple figures. But I don't know how I should proceed on my project. Defining each small surface one by one, sure will be **very** tedious. Should I learn some more? WebGL or something else? Or is the 'tedious' way an 'okay' way? What would you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The different angles" implies that you want to model and render a three dimensional object.

Here is one recipe to success:

- Design your model (grand piano) in any open source and free modelling application, like [Blender](http://www.blender.org/)
- Then, learn basics of [Three.js](http://threejs.org/) or similar WebGL framework which simplifies the complex process of rendering a 3D scene
- Export your model from Blender and import it to your Three.js JavaScript.

It is possible to render objects to `<canvas>` on Three.js without WebGL, but using WebGL backend simplies the process a lot and I highly recommend  sticking with WebGL.

[Here are is one of Three.js examples showing some modeled cars from different angles (cameras)](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_cubemap_dynamic).

HTML5 Canvas API is mostly useful for 2D graphics and does not suit for your purpose very well, as you have noticed with its limitations.

Comment: +1 @Shashwat Black: Yours is very ambitious for a first project.  This answer is probably the method you can use to complete in the timeframe of a school semester.

Comment: Sorry for being late to reply.
Actually the professor wants us to apply the algorithms learned in class. So using blender wouldn't be the right choice. I have been doing it the hard way. I started two days ago and I have the wireframe model prepared. I still have about 10 days before the submission is due. I'll have to complete visible surface detection, illumination and shading by then. Hopefully I can finish it in time. If i finish early I will look into rendering shadows as well.
Thank you for your reply. :)

Comment: [Here](http://i.imgur.com/XnG2Guf.png) is how it looks now. I know it's not the best, but I'm learning a lot.
Also if you have any further suggestions, that would be great..

Answer (score 0):

Use WebGL, Three.js aims to be very accessible. www.udacity.com have a course on 3d graphics that uses Three.js that is very good for beginning.
Real-time 3D graphics is basically about creating a 2d image that re-creates that effect of a 3d perspective and can be updated in real-time.
Going about this in a brute force way won't teach you anything about how this effect is achieved.